# Efficiently creating a simple parallax effect with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

So for one of my new projects, I decided to write a super simple parallax script for some background images on scroll. This is what I came up with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  parallaxScroll();
  $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    parallaxScroll();
  });
});

function parallaxScroll() {
  $(".parallax").each(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('reverse')) {
       $(this).css("background-position","center " + (($(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop())/2) + "px");
    } else {
       $(this).css("background-position","center " + (($(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop())/-2) + "px");               
    }
  });
}
```

My question is, **is this efficient enough?** If not, is there a better solution? I wasn't sure if using an .each() would be best for performance, but it seems to work fine. The reason I have the function run at document load is so when you scroll the page for the first time, the background image doesn't jump.

Comment: http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/ - just sayin'

Comment: That bases the effect off the position of your cursor. I have no need for that.

Comment: Efficient enough for what? Do you have performance problems?

Comment: Efficiency depends significantly on the rest of what you're doing. If you have 5 million elements with the `parallax` class, no, what you're doing is not efficient, but your problem is not with this function.

Comment: No, it seems to work fine, but I wanted to make sure it's not super inefficient. Obviously the simpler the better, so if there was something that would do this faster instead of using .each(), for example, I'd be interested in hearing other suggestions.

Comment: I only have 2 or 3 DIVs with this effect on a single page, max.

Comment: First of all, you should use the CSS transform property, it's more efficient. Then you use the JS function `requestAnimationFrame` this enables the browser to make the animation even more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `css` which sets the value *immediately*, consider using `animate` instead. It defers setting values using timers/requestAnimationFrame, ensuring that your animation does not block the UI, is async (runs pseudo-parallel to other code), and ensures that the animation is smooth.

Answer (score 0):

This is a plain JS solution, but you'll be able to port it to jQuery really easily:

```
var lastScrollY = 0;
var backgroundImageY = 0;
var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                            window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
                            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame;

window.addEventListener('load', processScrollEvent);

function processScrollEvent() {
    var innerHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
    var backgroundImage = document.querySelector('#background img');

    lastScrollY = document.body.scrollTop;

    var currBackgroundImageY = Math.round(((backgroundImage.scrollHeight - innerHeight) / 100) * ((lastScrollY / (innerHeight - scrollHeight)) * 100));

    if(currBackgroundImageY != backgroundImageY) {
        backgroundImageY = currBackgroundImageY;
        requestAnimationFrame(processScrollAnimationFrame);
    }
}

function processScrollAnimationFrame() {
    var backgroundImage = document.querySelector('#background img');
    var transforms = ['transform', 'oTransform', 'msTransform', 'mozTransform', 'webkitTransform'];

    for(var i = 0; i < transforms.length; i++) {
        backgroundImage.style[transforms[i]] = 'translate3d(0, ' + backgroundImageY + 'px, 0)';
    }
}
```

Comment: Something must be missing. Where is backgroundImageY defined?

Comment: Oh, sure. It's just initialized with 0 at the beginning of the file. See my edit

Comment: Well, it mostly misses a bind to the scroll event. As is, pretty much nothing happens. Otherwise, pretty simple and efficient. Thanks

Comment: Bind would only set `this` to whatever you pass, right? Since `this` is not used, it has no neffect, as you correctly pointed out. It would actually be just overhead, if you'd count each instruction  As always: you're welcome!